# Chrome devtools: How to execute a snippet from the devtool console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to execute a snippet from the console? I am currently using the snippet context menu to run the snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight your snippet and then press `Control` + `Shift` + `E` (Mac) / `Command` + `Shift` + `E` (Windows) to evaluate the snippet in the console.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/

Comment: Highlighting the snippet will involve a mouse click. I would prefer a completely mouse free solution.